# MathJax plugin creating error

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, cdn, mathjax

So we have been using mathjax on our website for over a year. recently we started receiving this message: "WARNING: cdn.mathjax.org has been retired. Check..."

We performed the necessary steps for migration, but now that we are using the new repository, we are getting an error message when trying to load Tex using CKEditor: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }" in: MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML:54

looking at the code thats creating an error, it seems to be a syntax error in the config file. (see image https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqMxo.jpg). By googling i found an old version of this code meant for the migration and it doesnt have the second last semicolon: https://gist.github.com/pkra/b02253d18a7c611fe0ffb4fbd5d6273b

This is creating issues for us, as it means fractions created in Tex doesnt show up in CKEditor

Is this a bug by CDN with their migration or is there a fix that i can use?

Comment: You might want to share a live sample that exhibits the problem. But also, why are you still using the retired address? You should switch to another CDN provider (as our blog post suggests).

Comment: Even when swapping to the alternative cdn provider as suggested in your blog post here: https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ it comes up with the same error. i changed my script to <script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?...">
</script> and it doesnt say its the retired version anymore, but i get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the error message is due to an issue in the accessibility-menu extension that should only affect older browsers (in particular, IE8 and below).  If you are using IE and your version is greater than 8, then that probably means your page is triggering one of IE's emulation modes for an older version.  Try adding

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
```

as the first line of the `<head>` section of you page to tell IE to use the highest version it can handle.

This issue will be fixed in the next release of MathJax, but if adding the line above doesn't fix it for you, you could request version 2.6.1 from the CDN rather than 2.7.1 (by changing that number in the cdnjs URL).

Comment: I am on MacOS Sierra Chrome so dont thing it was the first thing. However I changed my version from 2.7.1 to 2.6.1 and this fixed it. thanks for the help!